# Booking management system (Restriction of booking times)

Tags: python, django, function, datetime, django-models

I am currently trying to add a restriction to what dates and times a client can book.

Example..
My day starts at 8AM so I want only bookings from 8AM onwards. A client wants to book a slot from 7AM-8AM then they should receive an error saying something along the lines of "can only book 8AM-7PM".

currently I have done this code:

```
class AvailabilityForm(forms.Form):
    check_in = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', ])
    check_out = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', ]) 

def validate_checkin_time(check_in_time): 
    if check_in_time <= 5.59 or check_in_time >= 7.00:
        raise ValidationError("Check in times must be between 6:00AM and 7:00PM")

def validate_checkout_time(check_out_time):
    if check_out_time <= 6.59 or check_out_time >= 8.00:
        raise ValidationError("Check in times must be between 7:00AM and 8:00PM")

class Booking(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(validators=[validate_checkin_time])
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(validators=[validate_checkout_time])
```

My first question is.. am I on the right lines here using validation?

So looking at it I don't think the if statements are correct but im not entirely sure how to correct them. Also do I have to somehow add the format of datetime into the validate funcs?

I Also don't want to allow clients to book in the past. Is there a way to allow that in the functions at the same time or would I have to make a separate function?

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out I scrapped the idea of validating it. I have an availability function that will allow bookings  It took ages but it was literally:

```
from django.utils import timezone #NEW

now = timezone.now() #NEW

def check_availability(check_in, check_out, session):
    avail_list = []
    booking_list = Booking.objects.filter(session=session)
    for booking in booking_list:
        if booking.check_in > check_out and booking.check_in > now or booking.check_out < check_in: #NEW
        avail_list.append(True)
    else:
        avail_list.append(False)
return all(avail_list)
```

Literally just added to the logic and it worked fine now no one can book previous days.